# Relative path in Subversion externals definition doesn't work for me!

Tags: svn, externals

I know there is a question about [relative paths in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359302/relative-path-in-subversion-external-configuration), but it doesn't work for me.

The error I get is:

```
svn propset svn:externals "openscada_da_server_common ../../openscada_da_server_common/schema" /tmp/atlantis-trunk/org.openscada.da.client.viewer/schema
svn: Ungültige Eigenschaft svn:externals 
    auf »/tmp/atlantis-trunk/org.openscada.da.client.viewer/schema«: 
    Ziel »../../openscada_da_server_common/schema« ist ein absoluter 
    Pfad oder enthält »..«
```

The equivalent english version should be:

```
"Invalid %s property on '%s': target '%s' is an absolute path or involves '..'"
```

My question is Why? According to the subversion docs it is a valid value http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a bit futher in the page of the manual you refer to you'll notice the following:

> Also, the local subdirectory part of the definition cannot contain .. parent directory indicators (such as ../../skins/myskin).

For clarity, with relative paths, the correct order of the arguments for `svn:externals` is:

```
^/../otherRepo/trunk/path/to/dir     dir
```

Comment: but that refers only to the local path! And further I get the same error using ../openscada_da_server_common/schema instead of  ../../openscada_da_server_common/schema. I tried it because I wasn't sure about the paragraph either. An it would'n make sense for this feature if you could only reference things in your current path.

Comment: Well, the second part of the new (as of v1.5) svn:externals definition IS the local path.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I totally missed that the order of the arguments for the external definition changed. I should RTFM (with more open eyes)

Answer (score 4):

Swap the locations of your 2 parameters.

Comment: Can anyone clarify this and show it it should be correctly? What 2 parameters?