# Create svn external relative to my current directory

Tags: svn

I want the following situation:

```
 trunk/my_sv_code
 trunk/my_tb_code/my_sv_code
```

In which the copy of `my_sv_code` in  `my_tb_code` is an external.

How do I write an svn:externals property that is relative to the `my_tb_code` directory?

The Red Book, sadly, has few good examples of this.

Comment: So it looks like you just mark duplicates with a comment?

Comment: Bahrep, I could not find the button to mark this as a duplicate.  Where is that?

Comment: There is a chance that you don't have enough rep to mark questions as duplicate. The comment is added automatically once you mark it as duplicate (i.e. vote to close a question because it's a duplicate of...)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's answered here:

[Relative Path in Subversion external configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359302/relative-path-in-subversion-external-configuration)

Not sure how to mark this question as a duplicate.